# Camunda workflow with Java delegate expressions not showing in Cockpit

Tags: java, camunda, business-process-management

I have a workflow developed using Java delegate expressions. I have started multiple instance of this workflow using Caamunda engine rest API. The workflow runtime execution details are not showing in the Cockfit. I can see all workflow instances are completed successfully & history recorded correctly.

How I can see the runtime details like the currently executing  service task, delay details, number of concurrently executing instances in the engine ...etc.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using "straight through" processes, so they just run and finish without wait states (like timers, messages, user tasks). In the camunda community edition, you won't be able to see those, as the CE cockpit has no history view.
That differs if you use the enterprise cockpit, then you can switch from runtime view to history view.

As you already mentioned, you can still access historic instances via the REST or java API, so you could build a custom view if you are not going enterprise.

Comment: I can see the history details via REST API. My issue is I'm clueless what's happening inside engine until process is finished. The workflow take few minutes to complete. The only way to track what's going on via log only. If I moved from delegate approach to external tasks I can see runtime details in  cockfit.

Comment: I would have to see the bpmn for details ... as I said, a "straight through" process (also, depending on your timeouts, it can run for a while), will never write to the Database, because there is no wait point. 
External Workers forces a wait point, another option would have been to mark tasks as "async before/after" forcing the transaction to commit.

Comment: We have made a thoughtful decision to use delegates. Full workflow run in-memory & no reason to touch Camunda DB. But workflow delegates call DB's and many REST APIs. We are completely blind about engine concurrent execution details & each workflow status until workflow is complete.

Comment: Well, if it is a thoughtful decision, not being able to see the process while it is running is a consequence you have to accept.

Comment: At the time decision making we were unware about this issue. Now operation monitoring become a challenge.